# How to write SQL query to pull only not matching Email IDs

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I need to write a query to pull records which Email IDs are not matching in another table.

For example, I have a two tables whose structures looks something like this:

```
Table1
    ID    | Name    | Email ID
    101   | TOM     | TOM@gmail
    102   | KIM     | KIM@gmail
    103   | JIM     | JIM@gmail
    104   | RIM     | RIM@gmail
    105   | SIM     | SIM@gmail 

Table2
     ID   | Name    | Email ID
    101   | TOM     | TOMMOT@gmail
    102   | KIM     | KIM@gmail
    103   | JIM     | JIMMIJ@gmail
    104   | RIM     | RIM@gmail
    105   | SIM     | SIM@gmail `
```

So, I need to Pull only

```
    ID    | Name    | Email ID
    101   | TOM     | TOMMOT@gmail
    103   | JIM     | JIMMIJ@gmail
```

Comment: Hey, next time, if you could post your query -- working or not -- it'll make everyone feel better about pitching in and answering your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also do it without explicit JOINs, if you don't need to return any values from the other Data Extension.

```sql
select
  t2.ID
, t2.Name
, t2.[Email ID]
from Table2 t2
where not exists (
  select top 1 t1.*
  from Table1 t1
  where t1.[Email ID] = t2.[Email ID]
)
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to leverage LEFT JOINS and subqueries

```
SELECT Id, Name, EmailId
FROM   (SELECT TABLE2.Id AS 'Id', TABLE2.Name AS 'Name', TABLE2.EmailId AS 'EmailId', TABLE1.Id AS 'SecondId'
        FROM   TABLE2
               LEFT JOIN TABLE1
                 ON TABLE2.EmailId = TABLE1.EmailID) AS myTable
WHERE  SecondId = Null
```

I have never actually written SQL against Automation Studio but this SQL statement is valid in T-SQL (MS SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input, this query worked for me as I expected

`select
  t2.ID
, t2.Name
, t2.[Email ID]
from Table2 t2
where not exists (
  select top 1 t1.*
  from Table1 t1
  where t1.[Email ID] = t2.[Email ID]
)`